# Keycloak brute force attack detection at client level

Tags: authentication, keycloak, brute-force, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

There are details on how to set brute force attack detection in 'Realm Settings' for user logins. Is there a way to handle this at client level? Where we can apply settings for specific clients to stop bruce force attacks?

There are particular clients that hit our service (for logins) & overload us, we are looking to block them via Keycloak.